# PHP and ACF - Is it possible to do if/else in regards to field name to output value?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I am at the moment doing shortcodes for ACF, and wanted to know if there is a way of shortening it, instead of re-creating the same shortcode again and again, only to change the $value.

Here is the code:

```
function acf_shortcode_distance( $atts ) {
  
  // extract attributs
  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'field'      => '',
    'post_id'    => false,
    'format_value'  => true
  ), $atts ) );
  
  
  // get value and return it
  $value = get_field( $field, $post_id, $format_value );
  if (empty($value)) {
    return '';
  }
  
  // array
  if( is_array($value) ) {
    $value = @implode( ', ', $value );
  }
  $value = '<img src="distance-logo.svg" alt="distance-logo" class="svg-img"><br/><p>Distance: '.$value.'</p>';
  // return
  return $value;
}

add_shortcode('acf_if_value_distance', 'acf_shortcode_distance');
```

What I need is to make value outputs in regards to the given ACF field I am using. Something like:

```
  if( is_array($value) ) {
    $value = @implode( ', ', $value );
  }
--- IF FIELD = DISTANCE, OUTPUT THIS:
  $value = '<img src="distance-logo.svg" alt="distance-logo" class="svg-img"><br/><p>Distance: '.$value.'</p>';

--- IF FIELD = TIME, OUTPUT THIS:
  $value = '<img src="time-logo.svg" alt="distance-logo" class="svg-img"><br/><p>Time: '.$value.'</p>';

--- ETC. ETC. FOR EACH NEW FIELD
  // return
  return $value;
}
```

Is there any way around doing this? Everything I've tried does not work, and I think re-creating the whole shortcode for the 15+ fields I have is a bit extreme!

I hope someone can guide me on the way, thanks in advance!

Comment: You could create a helper function that acts like a getter and define the return values on the function like `$value = getFinalValue('field_name', 'compare_against', 'string_if_true', 'string_if_false'); And then you just call the getFinalValue for any other field that you need. This is a common pattern for DRY (don't repeat yourself). Could you provide more conditions what you wanna compare and which fields you need?

Comment: How would that look? I'm still not super comfortable with PHP, so not entirely sure how it all works yet. It does sound like something that would do the trick! Where would it get the field name from?

Comment: Seems like wrapping them in an if statement did the trick. Not sure why I didnt see that!
```
   if ($field === ('distance')) {
  $value = '<img src="distance-logo.svg" alt="distance-logo" class="svg-img"><br/><p>Distance: '.$value.'</p>';
  // return
  return $value;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at a switch statement for this - https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Avoids a lot of if, else if and makes it easier and cleaner to follow the logic. Which could be nothing if empty or doesn't have a match.

Comment: You are absolutely right, for some reason I've sweat out that switches exists. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: If this works as the answer please flag it so it helps others in the future with something similar.